# What skills provide what elemental damage for elemental exposure wizard?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

So we need fire, cold, arcane, and lightning.

Say I have

sparkflint familiar. Does that give fire?
Frozen orb. Okay cold covered
Arcane? How do I get arcane? Arcane hydra?
Lightning comes from electrocute

Is that how most builds in http://diablo.somepage.com/popular/wizard works?

They don't seem to have arcane hitter at all?

Comment: I believe Magic Weapon with the Force rune gives you arcane damage even if your attack was some other element. I've seen arcane damage go off sometimes on a cold immune boss when using glacial spike magic missile (which would ordinarily be cold), but haven't fully tested enough to be certain.

Comment: I do not think magic weapon changes your attack type at all. Familiar, however, have their own attack. Fiery's familiar attack is still arcane though.

Comment: Remember that the elemental damage from your weapon also stack to the damage type. So for example, if your weapon has +1000-1400 fire damage, it will also give a +5% stack from fire

Answer (score 2):

You do not necessarily need all four elements. If you consistently have three stacks up, that is 15% extra damage, which is the same as Glass Cannon. Of course, you will not always have all the stacks, but it is probably still one of the best passives for damage.

Comment: No, it's way better than glass canon with 3 stacks. Glass canon gives 15% bonus damage to skills (which scales additively with other "bonus damage to skills" as you can see in details of inventory page ingame, and you usually have a lot of that)

On the contrary, Elemental Exposure is a different, far rarer bonus type: "Ennemies takes +X% percent damage" which scales multiplicatively with every other bonus type (and chances are high that you don't have other "Ennemies takes +X% percent damage", the only other I know on wizard is frost nova-cold snap)

Answer (score 1):

Skills by damage type (if no rune is mentioned, the default skill, and some or all runes, will use that damage type; otherwise, specific runes mentioned are the only variants to do that damage type):

**Arcane:**

- Magic Missile
- Arcane Orb
- Arcane Torrent
- Energy Twister
- Disintegrate
- Hydra - Arcane Hydra Rune
- Familiar
- Archon
- Meteor - Star Pact Rune
- Teleport - Calamity Rune
- Mirror Image - Mocking Demise Rune
- Explosive Blast
- Diamond Skin - Diamond Shards Rune
- Wave of Force
- Explosive Blast
- Black Hole

**Cold:**

- Arcane Orb - Frozen Orb Rune
- Magic Missile - Glacial Spike Rune
- Ray of Frost
- Frost Nova
- Ice Armor
- Hydra - Frost Hydra Rune
- Meteor - Comet Run
- Blizzard
- Shock Pulse - Explosive Bolts (the Diablo 3 [game guide](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/) lists this as cold damage)
- Energy Twister - Mistral Breeze Rune
- Black Hole - Absolute Zero Rune

**Fire:**

- Hydra
- Meteor
- Familiar - Sparkflint Rune
- Shock Pulse - Fire Bolts Rune
- Magic Weapon - Ignite Rune
- Magic Missile - Conflagrate Rune
- Arcane Orb - Scorch Rune
- Wave of Force - Heat Wave Rune
- Explosive Blast - Short Fuse and Chain Reaction Runes
- Black Hole - Blazar Rune

**Lightning:**

- Shock Pulse
- Electrocute
- Storm Armor
- Magic Weapon - Electrify Rune
- Hydra - Lightning Hydra
- Energy Twister - Storm Chaser Rune
- Meteor - Lightning Bind Rune
- Black Hole - Supermassive Rune

Comment: I can confirm sparkflint provides fire damage for the familiar.  It says so right in the tooltip.

Comment: @z-Thanks, I've updated. The online Game Guide just says "Summon a fiery familiar that grants you 10% increased damage." The in-game tooltip, as you say, specifies that it does fire damage.