# Does sparkflint familiar emit fire damage or arcane damage

Tags: diablo-iii

This is the explanation

Sparkflint

> Summon a **fiery** Familiar that grants you 10% increased damage.

Comment: the answer to your question has been covered here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162655/what-skills-provide-what-elemental-damage-for-elemental-exposure-wizard

Comment: also, if you mouse over a rune it will usually tell you what element damage type the skill will do with that rune.

Comment: The answer for fiery familiar is not clear. In that other question, the answerer claim that no known familiar uses fire damage. Also this question is far more specific.

Comment: it doesn't not matter if the answer is not clear, you can ask for clarification, not create a duplicate question.  Specificity doesn't matter either as they both cover the same thing.

Comment: This question is more specific. The other question is more general

Comment: Like I said, specificiy doesn't mean its not a dupe when the answer is already covered by the other question.

Comment: I've updated the answer in the linked question, and z - is absolutely correct: this is a dupe of the other.  Being far more specific is not an argument in this question's favor.

Comment: Seriously. You really think those questions differ? One ask for wizard's elemental exposure passive. Another ask for the type of damage of sparkflint familiar. I mean, even if answer for one could partially answer the other, the detail and focus is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fire damage according to these forum posts http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4552507627  http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12032393226

They say "Look at the tool tip when you highlight it in game, it says "Fire" in the background. If you mouse over the other Familiar variants you will notice they too all have their own elemental affix."

Hope that helps